# pandas dataframe breaking long table to multiple tables

Tags: python, json, sql-server, pandas, flatten

I have a dataframe which has a structure like below.
id, name, value, employee_0_salary, employee_0_skills_0_id, employee_0_skills_1_id, employee_1_salary, employee_1_skills_0_id so on..

Basically formed from a flattened json. But the number of columns exceed 1024. I couldn't copy the structure of json here but its a nested json with lists, arrays and dictionaries.

Now I want to split the dataframe so that the id column has duplicates but empoyee details comes as columns.

id  salary   skills_id

How to do it in pandas?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe melt() does what you want?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 1],
    'name': ['joe','sue', 'fred'],
    'employee_0_salary': [30000, 35000, 40000],
    'employee_0_skills_0_id': [101, 102, 103],
    'employee_0_skills_1_id': [103, 104, 105],
    'employee_1_salary': [32000, 36000, 37000],
    'employee_1_skills_0_id': [105, 106, 107],
    # Add other columns...
})
    
    print(df)
   id  name  employee_0_salary  employee_0_skills_0_id  \
0   1   joe              30000                     101   
1   2   sue              35000                     102   
2   1  fred              40000                     103   

   employee_0_skills_1_id  employee_1_salary  employee_1_skills_0_id  
0                     103              32000                     105  
1                     104              36000                     106  
2                     105              37000                     107  
    
    print(df.melt(id_vars=['id','name']))
    id  name                variable  value
0    1   joe       employee_0_salary  30000
1    2   sue       employee_0_salary  35000
2    1  fred       employee_0_salary  40000
3    1   joe  employee_0_skills_0_id    101
4    2   sue  employee_0_skills_0_id    102
5    1  fred  employee_0_skills_0_id    103
6    1   joe  employee_0_skills_1_id    103
7    2   sue  employee_0_skills_1_id    104
8    1  fred  employee_0_skills_1_id    105
9    1   joe       employee_1_salary  32000
10   2   sue       employee_1_salary  36000
11   1  fred       employee_1_salary  37000
12   1   joe  employee_1_skills_0_id    105
13   2   sue  employee_1_skills_0_id    106
14   1  fred  employee_1_skills_0_id    107
```

then, to return to the original it is messy because of the duplicate in the id column.  This is one way which adds a level to the row index so the pivot works, then drops it:

```
print(meltdf.reset_index().pivot(index=['index','id','name'], columns='variable', values='value') \
                    .droplevel(level=0) \
                    .groupby(level=0) \
                    .transform(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda k: pd.isna(k))) \
                    .dropna(axis=0))

variable  employee_0_salary  employee_0_skills_0_id  employee_0_skills_1_id  \
id name                                                                       
1  joe              30000.0                   101.0                   103.0   
2  sue              35000.0                   102.0                   104.0   
1  fred             40000.0                   103.0                   105.0   

variable  employee_1_salary  employee_1_skills_0_id  
id name                                              
1  joe              32000.0                   105.0  
2  sue              36000.0                   106.0  
1  fred             37000.0                   107.0
```

​

Comment: I used melt to rename the variable column to just salary and skills. Now is it possible to unmelt the 2 columns variable and value? pd.pivot is not working because id column has duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2],
    'employee_0_salary': [30000, 35000],
    'employee_0_skills_0_id': [101, 102],
    'employee_0_skills_1_id': [103, 104],
    'employee_1_salary': [32000, 36000],
    'employee_1_skills_0_id': [105, 106],
    # Add other columns...
})


reshaped_data = []

for employee in range(2):  # Update this based on the actual number of employees
    for skill in range(2):  # Update this based on the actual number of skills per employee
        salary_col = f'employee_{employee}_salary'
        skill_col = f'employee_{employee}_skills_{skill}_id'

        temp_df = df[['id', salary_col, skill_col]].copy()

        temp_df.rename(columns={salary_col: 'salary', skill_col: 'skills_id'}, inplace=True)

        reshaped_data.append(temp_df)

final_df = pd.concat(reshaped_data)

final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

print(final_df)
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know the range for both. Its dynamic and changes for each record. Also I have given only 2 fields here(employee - salary,skill) but there are more than 10 fields and that gets dynamic as well.